# How do I use Android's Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA to set wallpaper, contacts photos etc in Android

Tags: android

I have been trying to set image for different purposes e.g wallpaper, contacts photo, whatsapp profile... using Android Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA. I want to support Android O and NOT use [WallpaperManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html). So i use [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to get my Uri as below

```
    File imagePath = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null), "images");
    File newFile = new File(imagePath + File.separator + "images", "share_image" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
    bmpUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.mydomain.provider", newFile);
```

The setImageAs() is a as follows;

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.setData(bmpUri);
    intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/*");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set as:"), 7575);
```

Also set the paths and provided the paths as required. in the manifest

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.mydomain.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

And xml file in res/xml folder as

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-files-path
    name="files"
    path="images/" />
```

Am I doing anything wrong? If yes, how should I go about it? My code worked well with android api < 26 using `Uri.fromFile(file);` i.e before introducing `FileProvider.getUriForFile`

Comment: [Muzei](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nurik.roman.muzei) supports `ACTION_ATTACH_DATA` with content Uris. What app are you testing with?

Comment: @ianhanniballake my application i am developing. Please give me a more specific answer. at least I tried being specific with my question.

Comment: So does your app work with Muzei or not? If not, what error message appears in logcat?

Comment: @ianhanniballake  No, I do not use Muzei. No error in the logcat. Emulator shows "cannot edit an image under 50X50  pixels".

Comment: @ianhanniballake You down voted. Really?!!  When all you wanted is me to use Muzei. Cheap!

Comment: If you're not willing to debug your app by trying something and reporting its result in order to rule out a whole class of problems, then I don't know how you expect someone to give you a good answer.

Comment: Question: Am I doing anything wrong? If yes, how should I go about it? (conditional)

Comment: You could be doing 3 different things wrong. Testing would have ruled out 2 of them.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Muzei is a totally different thing from what I hoped for when I posted this question. Thanks for the contribution to Muzei. But, it was not worth a down vote.

Comment: I was asking you to test your app with Muzei, which I know supports content:// URIs. It was not meant to replace your app, but to test your app's usage of the `ACTION_ATTACH_DATA` Intent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168065/discussion-between-tonui-nicholus-and-ianhanniballake).

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it to work by writing data to the created file. this is my final code. (Note I was creatingTemp image file in the uri)

```
    File imagePath=new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null),"images");
    imagePath.mkdir();
    File newFile=new File(imagePath+File.separator+"images","share_image"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
    newFile.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=new FileOutputStream(dest);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,fileOutputStream);
    fileOutputStream.close();
    bmpUri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"com.mydomain.provider",newFile);
```

Remember to catch `IOException` and `FileNotFoundException`